# Optional @OneToOne and update not working

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I have the case where a `LiveStreamInformation` object can belong to either a `TwitchAccount`, a `YoutubeAccount` or a `Mixer Account`. In action, a `LiveStreamInformation` object will only belong to one of these Account objects. These are the mappings I have set, but when I preform operations such as:

```
TwitchAccount account = findById(id);
account.setLiveStreamInformationObject(info);
update(account);
```

The change is not made (but fails silently). Here are snippets of how the hibernate mappings are setup:

TwitchAccount:

```
public class TwitchAccount {
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "twitchAccount", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private LiveStreamInformation liveStreamInformation;
}
```

LiveStreamInformation:

```
public class LiveStreamInformation {

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "liveStreamInformationId")
    private TwitchAccount twitchAccount;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "liveStreamInformationId", referencedColumnName = "liveStreamInformationId")
    private MixerAccount mixerAccount;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "liveStreamInformationId", referencedColumnName = "liveStreamInformationId")
    private YoutubeAccount youtubeAccount;
}
```

Note that YoutubeAccount and MixerAccount have the same exact structure/mapping as TwitchAccount (just with its respective mappedBy)

Here is an example of how we try and set the live stream information object to an account

```
if (info != null) {
    LiveStreamInformationResponseDto dto = info.convertToResponseDto();
    dto.setUser(f.getFollows().convertToResponseDto());
    liveStreams.add(dto);
    // add/update to db for future checks
    persisted = liveStreamInformationService.create(info);
    twitchAccount.setLiveStreamInformation(persisted);
    update(twitchAccount);
}
```

The update method looks as follows (and works in every other case in my application)

```
@Override
public void update(final T entity) {
    Preconditions.checkNotNull(entity);

    getDao().save(entity);
}
```

I guess my question is do I have the mappings setup since its really an @OneToOne or @OneToNone (which doesnt exist), and why is it not updating correctly?

Comment: Is there a specific reason that you try to have three @OneToOne relationships in `LiveStreamInformation` with the same join column? Did you manage to store a `LiveStreamInformation` without assigning it to a account?

Comment: @felix-seifert, its the same name join column, but the actual columns exist over three different tables. specifically, twitchaccount,youtubeaccount,and mixeraccount all have their own livesteraminformation foreign key

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `twitchAccount` on the `LiveStreamInformation` instance:

```
persisted = liveStreamInformationService.create(info);
persisted.setTwitchAccount(twitchAccount);// Here is the new line
twitchAccount.setLiveStreamInformation(persisted);
update(twitchAccount);
```

Comment: I added the suggestion you made as well as the one below. I get the same functionality as before.
persisted = liveStreamInformationService.create(info);
persisted.setTwitchAccount(twitchAccount);
liveStreamInformationService.update(persisted);
twitchAccount.setLiveStreamInformation(persisted);
update(twitchAccount);

Comment: @yasgur99 Can you make a proof-of-concept project on Github?

Comment: @yasgur99 That is not what I said. Just use my code.

Comment: here is the proof of concept. I tried the solution you gave and it works the same as with the update to live stream information: https://github.com/Yasgur99/LiveStreamInformationPOC.git

Comment: @yasgur99 I need a functional project, since I don't know even what database you are using.

Comment: I apologize as this is as much as i can show because it’s a private codebase. I can assist with as much information as I can but cannot just post the entire project. I do feel as that poc contains all of the relevant code. I am using a mysql database

Comment: I think I found one of the issues. I had the mappings backwards, as the account classes owned the foreign key. I switched the OneToOne mappings, and the account class not persists the id, but if i try a lookup, i get 12:09:39.014 [http-nio-5000-exec-4] WARN  c.m.c.w.RestResponseEntityExceptionHandler - Conflict: Unable to find com.mergg.webapp.persistence.model.LiveStreamInformation with id 483; nested exception is javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find com.mergg.webapp.persistence.model.LiveStreamInformation with id 483